# Finding SyntaxNode of an ISymbol

Tags: c#, roslyn

Given a `SemanticModel` instance and an `ISymbol` assosiated with it, is it possible to get `SyntaxNode` of the `ISymbol`?

Basicly the opposite of `GetDeclaredSymbol` method of `SemanticModel`

the only way i am aware of is searching the `SyntaxTree` root with a predicate, is there a way to do it with less code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get the `SyntaxNode` declaration(s) from a `ISymbol`, use `ISymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences`.

Notice that it can return multiple references (f.e. when you've got a partial declaration) or none (when it is declared externally).

A small example:

```
var syntaxReference = propSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences
                                .First()
                                .GetSyntax();
```

`GetSyntax()` will return a `SyntaxNode` so you should still cast it to the exact type you're interested in.